# Sum of series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{(2n-1)3^{n-1}}$

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

How do I work out the sum of $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{(2n-1)3^{n-1}}$$

I have $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(\frac{-1}{3})^{n-1}}{(2n-1)}$

I let $x=\frac{-1}{3}$. So
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(x)^{n-1}}{(2n-1)}$.

I think I need to use term wise integration and differentiation but I am not sure how.

Comment: Are you familiar with $\sum\frac{k^n}{n}$?  Perhaps try representing this series as the difference of two series, each of which being easier to write and compute.

Answer (score 2):

Note by integrating the series for $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ term by term, that for $|x|\lt 1$ we have
$$\arctan x=\sum_1^\infty (-1)^{n-1}\frac{x^{2n-1}}{2n-1},$$
and therefore
$$\frac{\arctan x}{x}=\sum_1^\infty (-1)^{n-1}\frac{x^{2n-2}}{2n-1}$$
Let $x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$.
Our series has sum $\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{3}}$